# Nested routes in ember engine routes.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-engines

How to define nested routes in ember routable engine? I can't navigate to beyond 2 trees. Like,
For example

```
All posts
 Post
   Comments
     Comment
```

I can access

localhost:4200/posts/:postid/

But when I access

localhost:4200/posts/:postid/comments/:commentid

Its not rendering the content for comments template. But it doesn't show any error either.

Comment: could you share `router.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal

```
$ ember g route posts
$ ember g route posts/post
$ ember g route posts/post/comments
$ ember g route posts/post/comments/comment
```

In your router.js, replace the contents by the following

```
Router.map(function(){
    this.route('posts', function() {
        this.route('post', {path: '/:post_id' }, function() {
            this.route('comments', function() {
                this.route('comment', {path: '/:comment_id'});
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This is a solution, But what I prefer is , define an index sub-route in every main routes, for example `ember g route posts/index` and add it into your router.js like

```
this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.route('post', {path: '/:post_id'}, function() {
        .....
        .....
    });
});
```

add an index sub route every time